# Why is String.fromCharCode() not returning the correct character?

Tags: javascript

String.fromCharCode() sometimes returns the wrong character or no character if I enter a character code. I have tested it with some of the decimal codes in this table:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

For example, String.fromCharCode(0246) doesn't return ö but a completely different character:
[image]

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fromcharcode

Am I doing something wrong or why is String.fromCharCode(0246) not returning ö ?

I use Safari Version 13.1 on my iMac.

Comment: Becuase code of `ö` is 246, not 0246... Try: `String.fromCharCode(246)`

Comment: A leading 0 indicates an octal number in JavaScript, so 0246 is 166, I suspect the character you got was ¦.

Comment: You can use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the method. `HTML` support Unicode.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '\u00F6';
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Or use as string, since `0` is start of octal number**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var res = String.fromCharCode('0246');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or just `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'ö';`.

Comment: Your examples have nothing to do with html

Comment: i have added 2nd example too @AndrewMorton